# Not sure why creating a QVector is causing a segmentation fault in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, vector, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I am trying to figure out why this `QVector` is giving me a segmentation fault.

To give a little background on my program, I have two dialogs that pop up before my `mainwindow` appears. These two dialogs store basic information (how many players there are, there names, and what piece they want). I created a `QVector` to store each of the player widgets (each player will have a space in the `mainwindow` allocated to them). When I try and add the information that I recieved from the dialogs into the `QVector` for `GUIPlayers` it creates a segmentation fault.

Here is the function where the segmentation fault is happening:

```
void MainWindow::setPlayerData(int _index, const QString &_name, int i)
{
    index.append(_index); // this is the index number that correlates to the piece they selected
    name.append(_name); // this is the name the player typed in
    players.append( new Player(name[i], index[i]) ); //create a player class based off of that information
    guiPlayers.append( new GUIPlayerVertical( players[i]) ); // <<< segfaulting on this line. 
}
```

I declared `guiPlayers` inside my `mainwindow` header file like this: `QVector <GUIPlayer*> guiPlayers;`

Inside the `guiPlayers` class (a dock widget to the sides of my central widget), I create a `QLabel` for the player's name and a text box.

Here is a shortened version of it:

```
GUIPlayer::GUIPlayer( Player* p ) {

  player = p;
  nameLabel = new QLabel( this );
  nameLabel->setText( player->getName() );

  scrollAreaWidget = new QScrollArea(this);
  scrollAreaWidget -> setGeometry(0, 30, width(), height());
  scrollAreaWidget->setMinimumSize(QSize(7, 100));
  scrollAreaWidget->setWidgetResizable(true);
  scrollAreaWidget->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
  scrollAreaWidget->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);

  pieces_text = new QLabel();
  scrollAreaWidget -> setWidget(pieces_text);
  pieces_text->setGeometry(0, 30, height(), width());
}
```

I have tried to debug my program by placing `cout` statements inside the `GUIplayers` constructor but none are ever printed.

My `GUIPlayerVertical` class looks like this (its just a constructor):

```
#include "guiplayervertical.h"
GUIPlayerVertical::GUIPlayerVertical( Player* p ) : GUIPlayer( p )
{
    setFixedSize(QSize(300, 300));
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    setFeatures(DockWidgetFeatures(NoDockWidgetFeatures));
}
```

If you all need any more information to help me debug please let me know, I tremendously appreciate any help you can offer. Thank you.

Comment: valgrind may give you some hints, if you are running on Linux. Compile with -g first.

Comment: Hi again. `int i` as parameter does not make sense, and is error-prone. If you are trying to access the player you just created, why not use: `players.append( new Player(_name, _index) );` and `guiPlayers.append( new GUIPlayerVertical( players.back() ) );`

Comment: i just tried that but it still segfaults me unfortunately.  I know for sure the player object I am passing in exists. What other reasons can there be?>

Comment: But it works if you only have `guiPlayers.append( new GUIPlayer( players.back() ) );` ?

Comment: no it unfortunately doesnt

Comment: Empty your GUIPlayer constructors completely for your tests, leave a single cout to see if you hit it.

Comment: oh phew i used valgrind and figured it out. do you guys know how I can print the new strings above the older strings in the scrollarea box?

Comment: If you solved the issue, please write an answer explaining what was wrong (possibly also edit the question to include any extra info so that the answer makes sense). Or just delete the question since there are no answers, if you haven't deleted a lot of things lately (too many deletes may trigger penalties).